# Passing argv from client to server using RMI

Tags: java, server, client, rmi, argv

Iḿ trying for the first time to use RMI and I do not know much about java, just the basics. 
So for starters, I'd like to program a simple calculator with the 4 basic arithmetic operations (+ - * /), where when executing on the terminal (linux):

```
java CalculatorClient <host> 1 + 2
```

therefore argv[0] is the host, and I'd like to pass argv[] to the server so it can remotely calculate and return the value.

I did get the basic working, with this code where the client only receives how many times the server has been accessed:

```
    // CounterServerCaller.java
    import java.rmi.*;
    public class CounterServerCaller {
        public static void main(String args[])  {

        try {
            Counter c = new CounterServer();
            Naming.rebind("Counter", c);
            System.out.println("Counter ready.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro:"+e.getMessage());}
        }
    }
```

.

```
    // CounterServer.java
    import java.rmi.*;
    import java.rmi.server.*;

    public class CounterServer extends UnicastRemoteObject {
        private int value;
        public int nextValue() throws RemoteException {
            return value++;
        }
        public CounterServer() throws RemoteException {
            super();
            value = 0;
        }
    }
```

.

```
    // CounterCliente.java
    import java.rmi.*;
    public class CounterClient {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
                String host = args[0];
                Counter c = (Counter)
                    Naming.lookup("rmi://"+host+"/Contador");
                System.out.println("Contador: "+c.nextValue());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

.

```
// Counter.java
import java.rmi.*;
public interface Counter extends Remote {
    int nextValue() throws RemoteException;
}
```

I did search for an answer but I can only find really complicated code, with CallBacks which I don't think is the simplest solution. Maybe I was searching using the wrong key words? Can anyone shed some light into this matter please?

Comment: There is nothing here that passes `argv` to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Counter extends Remote {
    int nextValue() throws RemoteException;
}
```

This remote interface doesn't meet your objective in any way. I don't understand why you posted it, or even wrote it.

What you need is something like:

```
public interface Calculator extends Remote {
    public int evaluate(String expression) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Have it return `long` or `double` or `BigDecimal` if you like, whatever you need.